# NullPointerException trying to update an entity that contain a pivot table with version field

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I'm trying to update a pivot table through an entity where exist as a collection, my pivot table has a version field, when it updates throw an NullPointerException

I'm using Java 8 and Hibernate as JPA provider

Main entity
"Carpeta.java"

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "car_subcarpeta_id", referencedColumnName = "sub_id")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private RjFicha fichaId;
```

Foreign key of "Carpeta.java"
"SubCarpeta.java"

```java
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subCarpeta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<item> itemCollection;
```

Pivot table relate to SubCarpeta
"Item.java"

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "i_subcarpeta_id", referencedColumnName = "sub_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private SubCarpeta subCarpeta;

@Column(name = "i_version")
    @Version
    private Integer version;
```

This is the part of the trace when describe the source of the NullPointerException

```sh
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.next(IntegerType.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.next(IntegerType.java:22)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Versioning.increment(Versioning.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getNextVersion(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.flush(AbstractEntityManager.java:459)
    ... 141 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is set the table field in the database as NOT NULL and DEFAULT 0.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN i_version i_version INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

That's because if the field is NULL the result entity of the merge will get the version field as NULL and will throw a NullPointerException later.

This is the code was used to update the entity:

```java
T toReturn = (T)this.em.merge(entity);
this.em.flush();
this.em.refresh(toReturn);
return toReturn;
```

Comment: Saved my day, been wondering figuring out hours trying to figure out whats up.

Answer (score 1):

Try primitive `int` instead of Wrapper class.

```
@Column(name = "i_version")
@Version
private int version;
```

Default value of Integer is null and int is 0.

As per IntegerType API Java Doc ,

```
@Override
    public Integer next(Integer current, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) {
        return current + 1;
    }
```

if you keep Integer class null+1 throws **nullpointerexception**.

Comment: I tried what you say but still getting NullPointerException, I will search for other entities that may be letting version in null

Comment: @sage393, Please share current pojo

Comment: Thanks Siva Kumar, I found the solution, the i_version field in the database it was null instead of not null and default 0, I will answer the question with the current DDL of the table